# To make $(K_4,+)$ ( the Klein-4 group ) a ring

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

How can we define an operation $.$ such that the  Klein-4 group $(K_4,+)$ becomes a ring $(K_4,+,.)$ ?

Comment: did you mean Klein group

Comment: @AdiDani: yes , sorry , I edited

Answer (score 2):

$K_4=\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}\times\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ (product of rings has naturally a ring structure, defined componentwise).

Answer (score 0):

What is the additive structure for the field with $4$ elements?

Comment: Eddie I don't think that $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}\times\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ is a field. I don't really understand your answer

Comment: The ring in Laters' answer is not a field.  But what is the additive group of $\mathbb F_4$?